# Как сравнивать два массива с обьектами в jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, юнит-тесты, jest

У меня есть 2 обьекта внутри у них есть свойство options это массив и внутри элементов массива есть обьекты со свойством variants который тоже является массивом, при сравнивании в jest выдает ошибку что элементы не на в том порядке, как это исправить ?

[Пример](https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveDaringExam)

Comment: сам код прикрепите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Илья Перейдите по ссылке "Пример"